# Flask is slow to query Mongdb

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I use flaks to build a admin website for monitoring MongoDB user data. My query is working but it is very slow.. It takes about 3~5 seconds to load HTML.

I tested insert query and it works less than 0.5 seconds. I don't think it is a server problem.

**Flask codes A** ( it uses pymongo to connect MongoDB )

```
@app.route('/admin/dashboard/phonebook')
def admin_phonebook():
    collection = db.phonebook
    cnt = collection.find().count()
    result = collection.find()
    for i in range(cnt):
        flash(result[i]['name'],'name')
        flash(result[i]['phone'],'phone')
    return render_template('admin/dashboard/phonebook.html',length = cnt)
```

**Flask Codes B** (It is same speed to show result like above codes)

```
@app.route('/admin/dashboard/phonebook_register')
def admin_phonebook_register():
    collection = db.phonebook
    result = collection.find().sort('reg_date',-1)
    cnt = collection.find({},{'_id':0}).count()
    for i in range(cnt):
        flash(result[i]['name'],'name')
        flash(result[i]['phone'],'phone')
    return render_template('admin/dashboard/phonebook_register.html',length = cnt)
```

Is this slow because I count entire database? The phonebook data table has only 20 results.

Comment: How many entries? This is pulling the entire collection. Where is your database? Where is your application hosted? What sort of hardware are you running on. All things to consider and information that you have not provided in your question.

Comment: @NeilLunn I added more information about situation. I don't think it is a server problem.

Comment: I am curious why you need the "for" loop in this "service" layer function, can't you just pass/bind/model in the entire result object and have it rendered by your template?

Comment: You are right.. I should send entire result to HTML. It is MongoDB which is JSON type database. I never thought to convert JSON data to HTML file. "for" loop was one of ways to show data in HTLM on Flask flatform.

Comment: How can I send entire result to html? Do I have to use JSON?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using different database server, it could be slow. Use jQuery to load your data on website.